# Does too much screen time really damage your brain?

Tags: brain, intelligence

So I was looking on the internet for articles to whether computers really damage your brain and I found that half of them say the do and the other half say the don't. Personally I don't think it does as majority of working people use computers in their day to day jobs and still have the same intelligence and cognitive ability after say, 10 or 15 years of using them.

So does anyone know wheter this sttement is true or not.

Thanks,

Ps. I'm not a biologist, I'm just a curious kid :)

Comment: "Damaging your brain" is far too vague a claim to be evaluated scientifically. If you can find a specific, notable claim, then skeptics.stackexchange.com is a good site for that question (check their Help to see what is on topic there). If you collect some background and have a specific question to ask about biology that can be asked here.

Comment: And of course it might depend on what you actually DO during that screen time.  Developing programs to solve problems in the sciences probably has different effects than say following social media.

Comment: JamesM, Rapidly moving images/cartoons/games for many hours per day modify the attention span and self control especially in children, and there is research for that area. It means that children can become confused when they don't have rapidly moving images and they are less able to focus on slow activities like reading, toys, etc. Perhaps read this, it's  a related scare article: https://time.com/5514539/screen-time-children-brain/ low self control i.e. when someone speaks to you and doesn't look calmly at you but looks around fast in all directions while thinking, can vary  with screen use.

Comment: @aliential: Interesting.  Perhaps that explains why I find rapidly moving images in video to be so annoying - I was never exposed to them in childhood :-)

Comment: Yes Garry Kasparov would not have had any chance of being a chess champion if he had cartoon network on TV as a kid. One study found that even 9 minutes of spongebob squarepants can shorten children's attention spans.